# Input validation with AWS AppSync

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

Is it possible to do input validation with AWS AppSync without adding another "layer" of interaction?

I feel like adding a lambda function will defeat the purpose of it.

What I would like to accomplish is at least some regexp validation on strings.

And if not, then how do people that use AppSync or similar solutions (firebase) do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's only regex validation without having to check the input against data in a data source, then you can prepend some validation logic inside the resolver request mapping template.

See below an example for checking if the input field matches is an email from the `myvaliddomain.com`. If it doesn't validate, we just abort and error the field.

```
#set($valid = $util.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?(myvaliddomain)\.com", $ctx.args.input))
#if (!$valid)
    $util.error("$ctx.args.input is not a valid email.", "ValidationError")
#end

## Rest of your request mapping template below
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for.
One more question if you don't mind: Since the first argument to `$util.matches` is a string, would it be possible to grab that Regex pattern from the Database itself?

Comment: Since you now have to wire multiple datasources to a single GraphQL field, you can use a pipeline resolver. Your pipeline resolver would be comprised of two functions, the first function would retrieve the regex pattern from say DynamoDB using a GetItem operation and do the validation inside the response mapping template, and the second function would actually run another operation only if the first function succeeds. Check out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/pipeline-resolvers.html for a complete explanation.

Comment: @SamuelE. Try using a "Wrapper Pattern" as described in this article: https://hackernoon.com/graphql-authorization-with-multiple-data-sources-using-aws-appsync-dfae2e350bf2. This will save you a lot of redundancy in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Just as note, make sure you check that the thing you're validating (such as email) hasn't already been catered for in the list of Scalar types that Amazon have already defined.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/scalars.html